# onclick or onchange in a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

i have tried to give an alert when user click on an option in a select.

```
<select id="Menunavigation" class="cs-select cs-skin-slide">
    <option  value="Home" data-class="icon-home-cod">Start</option>
    <option  value="About" data-class="icon-about-cod">About</option>
    <option  value="Services" data-class="icon-services-cod">Start</option>
    <option  value="Work" data-class="icon-work-cod">Work</option>
    <option  value="Contact" data-class="icon-contact-cod">contact</option>
</select>
```

How would you do it?

Comment: Always hook to the `change` event of the `select` directly, otherwise people who browse the web with only their keyboard cannot activate the events your JS listens for.

Comment: `$('#Menunavigation').on('change', function(){ alert();})`

Comment: try this it will work : `$('#Menunavigation').change(function() { alert();});`

Answer (score 8):

Always hook to the `change` event of the `select` directly, otherwise people who browse the web with only their keyboard cannot activate the events your JS listens for.

```
$('#Menunavigation').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    // do something...
});
```

Comment: If i now would use your code, and do alert(value); than it should alert me the value of the option right?
I have done it, but i dont get anything?

Comment: Yep, it should work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ufdLof9n/. Check the console for errors.

Comment: This is really strange, i have the same code. and it dont work at my site..:S

Comment: Yes i have checked it and i got 0 Errors

Comment: What do you see in the console if you add this line of code: `console.log($('#Menunavigation').length);`

Comment: console.log($('#Menunavigation').length);
1

Comment: I can't see a reason that isn't working then. Could you copy your code that doesn't work to a fiddle.

Comment: That fiddle doesn't work because you haven't included jQuery - you can see that error in the console. Add it and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/xn7z7wcu/1/

Comment: I really dont know why it dont wotk locally..
I have tried evrything

Answer (score 1):

Simply with this code:

```
$('#Menunavigation').on('change', 
  function() {
    alert('Clicked.');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Menunavigation').on('change', function() {
    alert('You selected - ' + $(this).val())
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Menunavigation" class="cs-select cs-skin-slide">
  <option value="Home" data-class="icon-home-cod">Start</option>
  <option value="About" data-class="icon-about-cod">About</option>
  <option value="Services" data-class="icon-services-cod">Start</option>
  <option value="Work" data-class="icon-work-cod">Work</option>
  <option value="Contact" data-class="icon-contact-cod">contact</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach your functionality on `change` event like so:

```js
$('#Menunavigation').on('change', function() {
  alert('Worked.');
});

// Or slightly shorter version
$('#Menunavigation').change(function() {
  alert('Worked.');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="Menunavigation" class="cs-select cs-skin-slide">
    <option  value="Home" data-class="icon-home-cod">Start</option>
    <option  value="About" data-class="icon-about-cod">About</option>
    <option  value="Services" data-class="icon-services-cod">Start</option>
    <option  value="Work" data-class="icon-work-cod">Work</option>
    <option  value="Contact" data-class="icon-contact-cod">contact</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have tried your code snippet, but it dont work on my side

Comment: Just click on "Run code snippet" button here and try to change the select box. I've just tested and it is working just fine.

Comment: Yeah here its working fine, i have added the code here by me locally. But it dont work, i dont know why:S

Comment: Well, if you are copy-pasting the code into your own, make sure you wrap the code above into dom-ready `$(document).ready(function() { // code here });` and make sure the select id is the same `Menunavigation`.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#Menunavigation').change(function() {
  alert('Worked.');
});


});
Its still dont work..

Comment: Note: Using JQuery makes it more difficult to switch to using modern virtual dom view libraries like React.